# Visual Studio 2022 cannot add apple individual account

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2022, apple-developer

I have been trying to connect my paid individual account to Visual Studio 2022
I have entered the keyName, Issuer ID, KEY ID and downloaded the private key exactly as in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/apple-account-management?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=vs
but when I click on add button nothing occur and no error message is shown,
[image]
I have also visual studio 2019 installed on the same machine but also cannot add the account using the user name and the password

any one has any idea about the reason

Comment: Did this occur before? you could update to the latest Visual Studio 2022 and have a try. [Visual Studio downloads](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/)

Comment: I have updated XCode command line tools and installed the latest version of VS on my Mac and it works there after that when I tried on windows it worked too I haven't update anything on windows

Comment: So you didn't do anything for vs on windows then it just fixed?

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this? Mine works in Mac but not in Windows 10 VS 2022.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you go into Tools > Options > Xamarin and add your Apple developer account by using the Apple ID that is affiliated with that account.
When that is complete, you can highlight it, then click on View Details to see your Certificates and Profiles. If none are there, create a Certificate and Download all profiles.

Comment: my problem is that I cannot add the account, I fill the info but when I click add, nothing happened I have updated the question please look at the attached image