# How can I resolve an error when adding my Individual Apple Developer account via an Api Connect Certificate to VS2022

Tags: ios, .net, visual-studio, maui

Following the process as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/apple-account-management?tabs=vs) for an individual apple developer account:

[Tools > Options > Xamarin > Apple Accounts, click on the Add button and select Individual Account...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OHB5.png)

Prompt for this information (Name, Issuer ID, Key ID and private key path) is received:
[Enter your App Store Connect API Key information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unguO.png)

Where that requested information is taken from this location:

[The Name, Issuer ID, and Key ID data can be found in App Store Connect by selecting Users and Access and then the Keys tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G54ZI.png)

Resulting error message is:

[Error adding account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QUQk.png)

There is no way to get around this error or any reference to what can be done.   Checking the log files C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Logs\17.0\ the following error message is logged:

```
Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient Error: 0 : An error occurred on the receiver while executing a post for topic xvs/idb/add-developer-account and client vs22896admin
Xamarin.Messaging.Exceptions.MessagingRemoteException: An error occurred on client private2ceaa0bafb while executing a reply for topic xvs/idb/add-developer-account ---> Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Contracts.AppleProvisioningException: Provide a properly configured and signed bearer token, and make sure that it has not expired. Learn more about Generating Tokens for API Requests https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=api-generating-tokens
   at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.AppleProvisioningManager.<GetUpdatedAccountAsync>d__13.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local\AppleProvisioningManager.cs:line 129
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.AppleProvisioningManager.<AddDeveloperAccountAsync>d__10.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local\AppleProvisioningManager.cs:line 53
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local.AddDeveloperAccountHandler.<ExecuteAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.Local\Handlers\AddDeveloperAccountHandler.cs:line 37
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.RequestHandler`2.<HandleAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\Handlers\RequestHandler.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessageHandlerManager.<>c__DisplayClass16_1`2.<<RegisterHandlerAsync>b__2>d.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessageHandlerManager.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.<ReplyAsync>d__32`2.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingClient.cs:line 0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.ApplicationMessageExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<OfResponse>b__1(MqttApplicationMessage m) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\Extensions\ApplicationMessageExtensions.cs:line 194
   at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Select`2.Selector._.OnNext(TSource value)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.<PostAsync>d__21`2.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingClient.cs:line 190: 09/02/2023 17:37:10Z
    DateTime=2023-09-02T17:37:10.6819570Z: 09/02/2023 17:37:10Z
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.MessagingClientPro Warning: 0 : An error occurred while executing the operation. The host connection is active and running so no retries will be attempted.: 09/02/2023 17:37:10Z
    DateTime=2023-09-02T17:37:10.6829658Z: 09/02/2023 17:37:10Z
```

I have searched online for various solutions to this issue, and nowhere have I found any possible resolutions.  This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74967908/visual-studio-2022-cannot-add-apple-individual-account) does not help, and there is no way for me to comment with this additional error details as my reputation on stack exchange is to low and does not allow me to add this as an additional comment.

Comment: Have you tried updating the Visual Studio 2022?  Cannot reproduce on the Visual Studio Community 2022 17.7.1.

Comment: Reinstalling the Visual Studio sometimes works. If it does not work, you could [Report a problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) with Visual Studio.